# Making a while loop variable global

Tags: php, while-loop, global-variables

I want to access the last row created by my while loop ( the last $var ). I've tryed something like this:

```
$bar= "";
while ($bar= mysql_fetch_array($foo)) {
    global $bar;
}
echo $bar
```

Why wont that work?

Comment: Not sure you understand what global does and definitely why you don't want or need it there. Remove that global line, then try print_r($bar) where you echo. If that does nothing, then your $foo query is probably returning no results.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the last time the condition in your loop is evaluated, `mysql_fetch_array` returns `FALSE`, which is assigned to `$bar`. When you use it after control exits the while loop, that is the value which is `echo`ed. To retain the last value, assign to another variable within your loop; that way, it will have the value of the last iteration *before* the condition evaluated to false, rather than *after*. For example:

```
$last = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $last = $row
}
var_dump($last)
```

Answer (score 1):

why not:

```
$bar = "";
$foobar = "";
while ($bar= mysql_fetch_array($foo)) {
global $bar;
$foobar = $bar;
}
echo $bar
```

I'm not really sure what you are doing with that global $bar, but the fact is just assign a variable what you want it to be and it will stay the correct value at the end because it is the last time it is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

By using while loop we can solve the global variable problem.First
fetch the data from data base,after that we assign that fetch value
in any variable to use in while loop.

```
$bar = "" ; 
while ($bar =mysql_fetch_array($foo)){ 
global $bar; 
$foobar = $bar;
} 
echo $bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of making `$bar` global because `mysql_fetch_rows` populates the $bar in the while loop. Each time the while loop runs, the contents of $bar is replaced by the next row of results from your MYSQL database and when `mysql_fetch_rows` has run out of rows, it fills `$bar` with a false boolean value.

```
$bar =""; // Value of $bar is "".

while ($bar = mysql_fetch_array($foo)) {
$bar // $bar is an array with a row from $foo
}
// mysql_fetch_array return false and the while loop was aborted, so we end up here
echo $bar // $bar is now false.
```

if you want to access all the rows that was retrieved from your database you could do something like this.

```
$foobar = array();
while ($bar = mysql_fetch_array($foo)) {
$foobar[] = $bar;
}
//Dostuff with $foobar, ex print_r($foobar);
```